# PHP if else condition giving 500 internal server error

Tags: php, wordpress, internal-server-error

I am using some code to show editor a link  to edit specific pages

but it is causing 500 internal server **error** for **users** who are **not-logged-in**

I am a starter and need immediate help
My code is

```
<?php
      global $current_user, $wpdb;
      $role = $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities';
      $current_user->role = array_keys($current_user->$role);
      $ncaps = count($current_user->role);
      $role = $current_user->role[$ncaps - 1];


    if ($role ==  "editor") {
    echo  '<div class="user-tips">

<h4><u>Edit Equity Market</u></h4>
<h5><a href="abc.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=215&action=edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Intraday Tips</button></a></h5>
<h5><a href="abc.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=221&action=edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Positional Tips</button></a></h5>
<h4><u>Edit Commodity Market</u></h4>
<h5><a href="abc.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=220&action=edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Commodity Tips</button></a></h5>


</div>';
    }

    else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should validate varying data, If it only happens to users that aren't logged in, then line 4 (`$current_user->role = array_keys($current_user->$role);`) might fail because there is no current user

Comment: check the server error log for details about the 500. I can't see simply echoing out a blank string would cause a 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using function [is_user_logged_in()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in):

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('edit_others_pages') ) {
    echo  '<div class="user-tips">
    <h4><u>Edit Equity Market</u></h4>
    <h5><a href="abc.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=215&action=edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Intraday Tips</button></a></h5>
    <h5><a href="abc.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=221&action=edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Positional Tips</button></a></h5>
    <h4><u>Edit Commodity Market</u></h4>
    <h5><a href="abc.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=220&action=edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Commodity Tips</button></a></h5>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

EDIT: I also improved the check for roles a little. See [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for others.